# how to edit the pre-built themes of Ext.js?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have received an Extjs project in which only the pre-built CSS files are available. how do I know their structure to edit them or replace them with other Ext.js pre-available themes? Are there anywhere pre-built Ext.js CSS themes available?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Sencha Themer and there you could choose the base theme such as Triton then you could change the styling based on your requirement.Once you have done the styling you could publish the css from the menu option. You will get the css files which you could replace in your application in the index.html file.

Comment: Thanks sahil! I'll verify this in coming days and see if it works :)

Comment: So it is possible to just replce those CSS's with another prebuilt CSS's ?

Comment: Yes but that would be one of custom theme generated by extending sencha prebuilt theme or sencha theme. You couldn't replace it with own creating css that has no reference of sencha theme.